Should the threshold for the Community♦-raised flag "20+ comments" be lowered from 20 to, for example, 10?
Many questions and answers get a lot of comments, even though comments are not intended for extended discussions. The Community♦ automatically flags questions and answers with more than twenty comments to the moderators. Moderators then usually move the discussion to a chat room.
I think twenty is a rather high number and would like to suggest lowering the current threshold, possibly to ten, so people are encouraged to take the discussion to chat much sooner.

Update 04.09.2024: I have turned this into a feature request on Meta Stack Exchange: Make the threshold for the current Community♦-raised flag "20+ comments a site-specific parameter to allow lower thresholds.

@Lambie Is the chatroom that difficult to find? Also, anyone with 1000 reps can create gallery chat rooms.

That was not my question at all. Apparently, I'm not allowed to ask a question.

@Lambie In what way are you "not allowed to ask a question"?

No matter what question I have asked, here or elsewhere on this site,my question is questioned. My question was clear, yet I had to resay several ways (as I recall), and have comments from others that had nothing to do with it. That is what I mean.

Yes, the lower the better.
I always wondered why there was no button available for non-moderators to move comments to chat  before that threshold is reached, or better to have a button that allows proactively creating a chat conveniently associated to a question as the existing ones are now.

"that threshold"? Which one. In ELL, it's seven comments and there is an automatic pop-up there to allow users to switch over to chat.

@Lambie The very same popup appears on FSE too, there is no doubt about it. The precise heuristic is more complex than just seven comments. That depends on the number of users involved. I don't think that there is any difference between sites otherwise Tsundoku's wouldn't have suggested to make it site specific in the first place.

But [conversational liaison] if it exists and can't be changed by us, why not just bring it into conformity with the other sites like ELL and ELU have? Why bother asking us? [suggested making it]. I know of no other that has 20.

@Lambie There is no evidence that FSE is different than ELL or ELU.

Don't you believe me? The pop-up appears after 7 comments on ELL. ELU may be a bit more but  ** I just counted on ELL.**

@Lambie There are probably two thresholds, the lower triggers the "move to chat" message when a two way discussion is detected and the higher when the overall number of comments reach it. I suspect 20 is the latter and maybe 6 or 7 the former. They are only guesses from my part, I'm not a mod and I haven't found any definitive explanation about it.

Yes & no. It depends what the discussion is about. Some discussions are useful, they add to the post and help to improve the Q and the A. So automation might hinder making a point around an issue. For those intervening it's easy to either erase whole or part of the discussion or move to the chat. I'm fully aware that requires good will and showing responsibility.

As far as I understand, there is no (full) automation involved in Tsundoku proposal, that's only a lowered threshold . A mod might still decide to keep what is relevant to the question and what is conversational.

I mean and move what is conversational to a dedicated chatroom.

This is absolutely right. The issue is more about whether or not the comments stick to the topic. Another point: Sometimes discussions about language can be very long, regardless of whether this is tiresome or not. It can be tiresome but relevant.

@Kamala-1FTW And my opinion is that users should be able to move a discussion to chat. Users. But I know  you think my opinion is worthless. Fine. But try to not misread what I said and denigrate it: Users should be able to move discussions to chat after some number of comments.

@Kamala-1FTW   "Mods have to do this" : I say  they don't have to,  users can and should, hence my mention of "good will"  & "responsibility" which you seem to have missed  in my answer. Users should be encouraged to be more responsible. In all the years I've been here I've deleted hundreds of my comments once they'd made their point. At times I haven't wanted to delete them when they are hints  I've given that have been converted into wikis "as is" with a link to my comment. [...]

A hint isn't an answer, it's just a transient info, the start of a thought to be chewed over, an unfinished thought that anyone could pick up and finalize.

@Kamala-1FTW T'es encore plus pessimiste que moi sur la nature humaine. Je suis d'accord que certains ne le feront jamais. Mais c'est peut-être à nous de les encourager, de leur dire que c'est possible.... Et je suis il y a pas plus lambda, ordinaire de chez ordinaire. Je crois juste en l'éducation avant la répression. Bien sûr quand l'éducation a échoué il faut d'autres mesures.

"Tu n'es pas un utilisateur lambda": What  does that  mean exactly?

@Lambie Any good dictionary will tell you.
